# Creating an array element-wise from product of two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, element

I have a project wherein, after multiplying arrays, I have to arrange them into a separate array (element-wise) and get their sums.

```
As an example:
a = [1, 0, 1]
b = [[3,5,2], [5,4,3], [5,2,2]]
c = a*b
c = [ [3, 5, 2]
      [0, 0, 0]
      [5, 2, 2] ]
```

Now, I want to put the answers in an individual array element wise such as:

```
r1 = [3, 0, 5]
r2 = [5, 0, 2]
r3 = [2, 0, 2]
```

Then, get its sum.

```
sum_r1 = [8]
sum_r2 = [7]
sum_r3 = [4]
```

So far, my I am only able to code the multiplication. I am still trying the appropriate code for the succeeding steps. My code looks like this:

```
 [EDIT]
 def fitness_score(a, b):
   c = numpy.multiply(a, b)
   trns = numpy.transpose(c)
   s = numpy.sum(trns, axis=1)
   return s
```

Output gives the answer but it has an error something like this: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (500,3) (3,3). Note that the values in a are obtained randomly.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: The error suggests that the `a` array has shape (500, 3) instead of (3,). That means that your example data in not fully relevant. You should show 2 2D-arrays with the expected result.

Comment: @SergeBallesta how can I change that if a is obtained using random function in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NumPy, just use transpose on the second matrix to get the desired result.

```
import numpy as np
a = [1, 0, 1]
b = [[3,5,2], [5,4,3], [5,2,2]]
a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)
mul = a*b.T
#array([[3, 0, 5],
#       [5, 0, 2],
#       [2, 0, 2]])

s = np.sum(a*b.T, axis=1)
#array([8, 7, 4])
```

If you have a `500 by 3` shaped array for a. You can try this:

```
import numpy as np
a = [[1, 0, 1] for _ in range(500)]
b = [[3,5,2], [5,4,3], [5,2,2]]
a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)

mul = [a_c*b.T for a_c in a]
#array([[3, 0, 5],
#       [5, 0, 2],
#       [2, 0, 2]])

s = np.sum(mul, axis=-1)

print(s)
```

Comment: Hello! I tried doing this code (please see question above for edit), it works but I keep getting an ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (500,3) (3,3). I am new to python. Can anyone explain this to me? Thanks

Comment: How can you get value error if it works? I suspect you provided a wrong data format for `a` and `b`. Check the updated answer which works `a` with shape 500x3/

Comment: Welcome, @Acee don't hesitate to accept/upvote an answer if it helps :)